# JavaScript/PHP problems with onclick event

Tags: javascript, php, syntax-error

If I use `math.rand` in my JavaScript every time I press the button it will automatically change to a string. But when I use with php code why does it only change once.

How do I fix this?

```
<input  type="text" id="adminrand" name="tokenid" placeholder="Enter Token" class="form-control" required>

        <?php 
         date_default_timezone_set('Asia/China');
         $tokentime=date('s');
         $tokentime1= date('i');
         $tokentime2=date('m') + date('d')+ date('y') + date('i');
         $token = 'Phcl' .  $tokentime .''. $tokentime1 . '' . $tokentime2;
        ?>

        <button  type="button" onclick="GenerateTokenx()">Generate</button>

        <script>
            function GenerateTokenx() {
                let r = Math.random().toString(36).substring(5);
                document.getElementById("adminrand").value ='<?php echo$token;?>';  
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Please clarify your problem, it's not at all clear what is going wrong here. If this is a JavaScript problem, please just provide the rendered HTML/JS from your browser's view source menu, not the PHP code.

Comment: They need the PHP code to generate the `$token` @miken32

Comment: When you inspect the document what is the value of the token?

Comment: Im a very sorry i will just edit the post

Comment: @JayBlanchard I get that, but it will be a fixed value in the source code; making it possible to reproduce any JS issues.

Comment: Maybe because the PHP run only once when the page is loading, so when you click on button GenerateTokenX() is triggered, but the value you print with <?php echo $token;?> never changes

Comment: Mr Jay Blanchard If itrigger the onclick event the input text is not changing. but if i use on trigger event of  math.randon the input text is always changing.  I want my php code to change everyminute. I use date(s) so i can see it imediately if the input text is changing

Comment: To refresh on every click without reloading you need to use Ajax otherwise you will need to reload the page to get a new token from the PHP

Comment: Please do not stealth edit your code; it may cause answers to become incorrect and lead people the worng direction.

Comment: <script>
            function GenerateTokenx() {
                let r = Math.random().toString(36).substring(5);
                document.getElementById("adminrand").value =r;
            }
        </script>  this code is working fine. Every time i click the button it always change string data. I want to put the php code onto the var r but when i click the button it show  string  but it will not change anymore I want to fix this code

Comment: You will need AJAX for that @HelloWorld

Comment: AJAX is only way thank you so much for the help i thought it could work with that same function. I need to study ajax first